# Base table or view not found in PermissionServiceProvider class even though table already exists. (Laravel 6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-forge

Yesterday I switch my log level from '**critical**' to '**error**' in production server (laravel forge) and I received the below error  continuously around every 5 to 10 seconds:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forge.permissions' doesn't exist in /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:78
```

I checked in the production DB and table migration was already run long back and also the table is already there:

[image]

Below is my boot function in **PermissionServiceProvider** class

[image]

I assume this error would have been generating since PermissionServiceProvider class was created. However due to larvel log level was set to 'critical' I didnt received it.

Even though issue is present, there is no problem in accessing the application, I can still use the permission features perfectly. However I am not able to set log level to 'error' as errors will continuously thrown. So I want to fixed it properly.

N.B.: I am not able to reproduce it in local development.

Complete error log:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forge.permissions' doesn't exist in /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:78
```

Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(78): PDO->prepare('select * from `...', Array) #1 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(331): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->prepare('select * from` ...')
#2 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(662): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database{closure}('select * from `...', Array) #3 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from` ...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(338): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure)) #5 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2159): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from` ...', Array, true)
#6 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2147): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#7 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2619): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Query{closure}()
#8 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2148): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#9 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(546): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#10 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(530): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#11 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get()
#12 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1622): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'get', Array)
#13 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1634): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('get', Array)
#14 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/app/Providers/PermissionServiceProvider.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('get', Array)
#15 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\Providers\PermissionServiceProvider->boot()
#16 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()
#17 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#18 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#19 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(590): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#20 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#21 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(839): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\Providers\PermissionServiceProvider))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation{closure}(Object(App\Providers\PermissionServiceProvider), 35)
#23 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(840): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#24 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#25 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(219): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#26 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#27 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#28 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
Next Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forge.permissions' doesn't exist in /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(83): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception::new(Object(PDOException))
#1 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(331): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->prepare('select * from `...') #2 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(662): Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select * from` ...', Array)
#3 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(629): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure)) #4 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(338): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from` ...', Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2159): Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#6 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2147): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#7 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2619): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->Illuminate\Database\Query{closure}()
#8 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2148): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#9 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(546): Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->get(Array)
#10 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(530): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->getModels(Array)
#11 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->get()
#12 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1622): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'get', Array)
#13 /home/forge/api.neoxtreme.app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1634): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('get', Arr…

Comment: `'forge.permissions'` ✋ question: is "forge" the name of your database?

Comment: No,  DB_DATABASE is 'serveneo_db' and 'forge' is the DB_USERNAME

Comment: I mean, `forge.permissions` indicates that your database name is `forge`. env file -> that's where you need to focus on first, I would say.

Comment: I checked in env file every thing is fine. This is from env file in the laravel forge: DB_DATABASE=serveneo_db
DB_USERNAME=forge. Not sure how come this 'forge' is treating as DB. This issue occurs only for the custom service providers that uses DB. IT does not occurs for the tables which are not in service provider.

Comment: I remember now, 'forge' was the initial database. Later we create a separate server and created 'serveneo_db'. But still not sure how come old 'forge' DB is using

Comment: Dont know, maybe try dumping autoloads, clearing caches and restart queue workers and stuff..?

Comment: Its working now, after restarting the server. I have tried php artisan cache:clear, config:cache, config:clear. But only after restart it is working now.